# php---which tool i can use to trace a cms source code

Tags: php, drupal

now, if i want to trace the drupal sourcecode.how and which tool i can use to trace the drupal source code?i want to make a quick walk-through to drupal code. and want to trace it myself,but i don't know which good debugger i should use and how to trace it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xdebug is an extension to PHP.

With it, you can get a Trace file every time a page is loaded, with a full list of every function called while rendering that page.

http://www.xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

Answer (score 2):

Try Drupal for Firebug http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug with firebug https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/ as addon in firefox

Comment: As it might not be clear: drupal for firebug lets you do debugging stuff that happens on the server, using firebug.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to find which methods was used and what values been passed until certain moment can be archived by outputting [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

like:

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

There are many IDE with integrated debuggers at most they work same way, as example above.
You can try Eclipse or NetBeans for free or Zend Studio for a fee.

Answer (score 0):

Have you played much with the [API Documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal)?  All of the core code is documented here, as well as providing a hyperlinked snapshot of the current HEAD for the particular major version you are browsing.  One you get a good grasp of how hooks and templates work, tracing through code this way is mostly easy.